# Why is the shape of the weight different?(Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

Im trying to to do SoftMaxRegression in 2ways

First Way:

```
x_train = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 1, 1],
           [2, 1, 3, 2],
           [3, 1, 3, 4],
           [4, 1, 5, 5],
           [1, 7, 5, 5],
           [1, 2, 5, 6],
           [1, 6, 6, 6],
           [1, 7, 7, 7]])
y_train=torch.LongTensor([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])

y_one_hot=torch.zeros(8,3)
y_one_hot.scatter_(1,y_train.unsqueeze(1),1)

W=torch.zeros((4,3),requires_grad=True)
b=torch.zeros((1,3),requires_grad=True)
optimizer=optim.SGD([W,b],lr=0.1)

nb_epoch=1000
for epoch in range(nb_epoch+1):
    hypothesis=F.softmax(x_train.matmul(W)+b,dim=1)
    cost=(y_one_hot*-torch.log(hypothesis)).sum(dim=1).mean()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if epoch % 100==0:
        print('{0}th epoch Cost:{1} '.format(epoch,cost.item()))
print('W:',W.shape)
print('B:',b.shape)
```

Then, W.shape is torch.Size([4, 3])

However, If I USE THE second Way:

```
class SoftmaxClassifierModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(4, 3) 

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
model = SoftmaxClassifierModel()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

nb_epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(nb_epochs + 1):

    
    prediction = model(x_train)

    
    cost = F.cross_entropy(prediction, y_train)

    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print('Epoch {:4d}/{} Cost: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch, nb_epochs, cost.item()
        ))
for name, param in model.state_dict().items():
    print(name, param.size())
```

Then, the output is linear.weight torch.Size([3, 4])
linear.bias torch.Size([3])

Shouldn't the size of the linear.weight torch.Size be (4,3)?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of torch.nn.Linear:

```
Init signature: torch.nn.Linear(in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True) -> None
Docstring:     
Applies a linear transformation to the incoming data: :math:`y = xA^T + b`
```

The weight matrix is transposed before it is applied to your data. So the shape is correct.